# «Она упала, и...» / «Она упала и...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, многоточие

Правда ли, что, если я хочу показать, что после многоточия должно следовать предложение, которое бы перед *и* делало запятую обязательной, мне надо её, эту запятую, ставить-таки, то есть:

`Она упала, и... [я к ней подошёл, чтобы её спасти.]`

Но:

`Она упала и... [сама таки поднялась.]`

Ещё:

`Она упала – и... [умерла.]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Ставим запятую перед "и" (ССП):
*Она упала, **и** никто даже не помог ей подняться* (Валентин Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным).
С многоточием: ***Она упала, и...***

**2.** Не ставим запятую перед "и" (однородные сказуемые):
*Она упала **и** затихла черным комком на белом снегу* (Татьяна Окуневская. Татьянин день).
С многоточием: ***Она упала и...***

**3.** Ставим или не ставим интонационное тире перед "и" (зависит от контекста):
*На пороге она упала **и умерла*** (Ф. К. Сологуб. Королева Ортруда);
*Он сделал один круг, и вдруг раздался такой звук, как будто барабан лопнул. Он упал **и умер*** (Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема);
*Пуля заставила его высоко, словно через барьер, прыгнуть. Он упал **— и уже не поднялся*** (М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон).
С многоточием: ***На пороге она упала и... Он упал и... Он упал — и...***

> 2. Тире, которое ставится между членами предложения для выражения неожиданности или для обозначения логического ударения, также имеет интонационный характер...

- При обрыве предложения перед "и" ставим те знаки, которые должны быть в полном предложении.

[Интонационное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94)